# Threads:pthread_create() output confusion

Tags: multithreading

I am trying to create threads using pthread_create.The threads,from their start routines, 'cout' to the console a simple msg after creation.I am trying to print the thread Id's too from the main function.
my code is :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;


void* start_proc(void* threadNo)
{
   
   
  
    
   pthread_mutex_t display;
   
  
  if(pthread_mutex_init(&display, NULL) != 0) {

     exit(-1);   
     }
  
   pthread_mutex_lock(&display);
   
   stringstream buf;
   
   buf<<"Initialized threadNo = "<<*((int*)threadNo);
   buf<<endl;
   
   cout<<buf.str();

   pthread_mutex_unlock(&display); 
    
   pthread_exit(NULL);
    
    return(0);
}

int main()
{


  
  int i =0;
  int k =0;
  
  
  pthread_t threadCount[5];
  
  for(k=0; k<5; k++)
     {
      int* ptr = &k;
      int errorCode=pthread_create(&threadCount[k], NULL, start_proc, (void*)ptr );
      
     
     
    pthread_mutex_t display2;
   
     if(pthread_mutex_init(&display2, NULL) != 0) {

     exit(-1);   
     }
   
   
   
      pthread_mutex_lock(&display2);
   
      stringstream buf2;
   
      buf2<<"threadCount  "<<threadCount[k];
      buf2<<endl;
   
      cout<<buf2.str();

      pthread_mutex_unlock(&display2);   
      
     
      
      
       if(errorCode)
        {
  cout<<"Error: return code from pthread_create= "<<errorCode<<endl;
  
 exit(-1);
 
 } 
      
     } 
      
   pthread_exit(NULL);
   
 return(0);
 
 }
```

***Now when I run a.out multiple times one after the other I get***

> Initialized threadNo = 0
> threadCount  2
> threadCount  3
> Initialized threadNo = 1
> threadCount  4
> Initialized threadNo = 2
> threadCount  5
> Initialized threadNo = 4
> Initialized threadNo = 4
> threadCount  6
>
> Initialized threadNo = 0
> threadCount  2
> threadCount  3
> Initialized threadNo = 1
> threadCount  4
> threadCount  5
> Initialized threadNo = 3
> threadCount  6
> Initialized threadNo = 4
> Initialized threadNo = 5
>
> threadCount  2
> threadCount  3
> threadCount  4
> threadCount  5
> threadCount  6
> Initialized threadNo = 5
> Initialized threadNo = 5
> Initialized threadNo = 5
> Initialized threadNo = 5
> Initialized threadNo = 5

Each time I run it i get some different pattern.Can someone help and explain why this is??
I was first not mutexing cout, then i looked up in the NET and incorporated that to try make it thread safe

Answer (score 1):

1. `pthread_mutex_t display;` is local in the thread function (as well as in `main::for`), so each thread locks and unlocks different mutexes.
2. You pass the address of `k` to the thread function, for the first thread it is the same as for the fifth.

Comment: Thanx for the first point.Indeed.Tha mutex should have been declared globally i.e at file scope and also should be initialized once from inside main().

Comment: But your second answer dosent explain the behaviour.a pointer to k(ptr) is being passed to the start routine by design.So each time the for loop is executed its value is incremented.So when it's being dereferenced from inside the start routune and printed(using cout), it should print the incremented value.This doesnt explain the irregular output pattern, where thread id is being repeated 5 sometimes or 0,1,2,4,4 etc.

Comment: I have figured the problem out.we cant be sure when a thread will be created and and after creation starts running(it's decided by the OS).So it may happen that the for() loop goes to the next execution and increments k, but the thread created in the previous iteration hasn't yet run and by the time it runs and reaches the stage where 'ptr' is dereferenced(from inside the start routine) it has been incremented.so now two thread will print out the same 'Thread Id', even though they are different threads.\